# DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") displays date as intended, but on save it's converted wrong

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As the topic says:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
public DateTime? KeyStartDate { get; set; }
```

That works great displaying it:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="KeyStartDate">@Resources.Global.StartDate</label>
    <input data-toggle="datepicker" asp-for="KeyStartDate" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="KeyStartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

but when I submit the form the date is parsed wrong e.g. "MM/dd/YYYY". So if I choose the date 01.02.2019 (February 1st) the thing interprets it as 01/02/2019 (January 2nd).

What to do?

EDIT:

The datepicker part:

```
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({ format: 'dd.MM.yyyy' });
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap datepicker? Sounds like the problem originated from default behavior of the datepicker library you're using.

Comment: Disabled the datepicker entirely and manually entered the date. Same thing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked: (in startup.cs)

```
var defaultDateCulture = "fi-FI";
var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultDateCulture);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

// Configure the Localization middleware
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    }
});
```